# UI framework reference GoogleAPIs, resulting in access to fonts error

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

My project applied `Semantic-UI`, which imported **GoogleAPIs**, but it can't be got in *China*. what's the best solution to this situation?

**GitHub** Address: [Demo-Online](https://github.com/zhangyuanliang/flow-chart)

Bug: [img_bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyuST.png)

Semantic.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin');
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use other npm module instead.
Modules **semantic-ui-offline** or **semantic-ui-css-offline** were forked from semantic-ui, try use one of them instead **semantic-ui-css**

```
npm i semantic-ui-offline
```

or

```
npm i semantic-ui-css-offline
```